# aiohttp limit NEW connections per minute

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I want to limit the new connections that are created per minute.

There is no max_concurrent_connection limit. The only constraint is that 20 new connections are allowed each minute.

Comment: What are you connecting to? Do you have the full list of resources you want to connect to in advance, or are you generating it as you go?

Comment: @user4815162342 I do have the complete list of resources I want to connect to. But I don't know how long each if them will take to download.

Comment: Try using the `Limiter` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66521053/1600898): `limiter = Limiter(3); responses = await asyncio.gather(*[connect_to_remote(limiter, url) for url in urls])`. The `connect_to_remote` should begin with `await limiter.wait()` to wait for the correct time to establish a new connection.